# How to call functions from gs file using HTMLService?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

This is driving me nuts. I've written a html page for my Google web app which has functions written in a .gs file. All I am trying to do is call the functions from the .gs file from the .html file. However, every method I have tried does not seem to work. I know my functions work because they work when I run just them. I am missing how to connect the .gs file to the .html file.

my .gs file looks something like this:

```
function doGet() {

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function test()
{
  //getFormattedSpreadsheet("1xPDJJfCqWb2igug3NCFmJJ5nO49U6CK8mLwtaD727AY", "17qcsYh8M-cOwTg9K7sqqnKm0pGgEo6r7x1PguRf9Jk8", "Select School");
  archiveSheet("1wTNing5LAOYHbscQ_DTktIxvWcyc6gw6ZNTvAJDtkTo", "1ugNP0Pp97tnRKHLHa50j-QKx-4ynCfg3zHxtJTayiVk");

}
```

I need the function to be called on a button click, I tried things like (or even without the google.script.run portion):

```
<button onclick="google.script.run(test())">Full</button>
```

but I can't get my button to actually call scripts. I've read you can call scripts to run by just putting them in function() tags as well, but I need this to run on click rather than on load. Perhaps I just don't understand the link between the .gs and .html file. They are seperate files, but within the same Google web app project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is just slightly wrong.  You have:

```
<button onclick="google.script.run(test())">Full</button>
```

Should be:

```
<button onclick="google.script.run.test()">Full</button>
```

You had a parenthesis where there should be a dot.

[Google Documentation - Google Script Run API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: I'm frustrated that I completely missed that after hours of searching. I'm very very thankful that you saw it. Just tested this, and it works like a charm! Thanks so much!